# Could not find rake-12.2.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After running the `rails g controller` command I get this is my error:

> Could not find rake-12.2.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
>
> /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in
>   materialize': Could not find rake-12.2.1 in any of the sources
>   (Bundler::GemNotFound)    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in`map!'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize'
>     from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:159:in`specs'
>     from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:218:in
>   `specs_for'   from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:207:in`
>   requested_specs'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:109:in `block in
>   definition_method'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:21:in`setup'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'   from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:20:in`'
>     from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   /root/Desktop/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/commands.rb:33:in
>   `<module:Spring>'     from
>   /root/Desktop/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in`
>   '    from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   /root/Desktop/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/server.rb:9:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'     from
>   /root/Desktop/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/server.rb:9:in`
>   call'    from
>   /root/Desktop/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in
>   `call'    from
>   /root/Desktop/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in`
>   run'     from
>   /root/Desktop/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in
>   `'

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`? Try running it with `bundle exec`.

Comment: I've already done

Comment: gem install rake

Comment: place this in your gem file gem install rake -v '12.2.1'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by choosing different version of ruby SDK. In my case it was by selecting 2.4.2 instead of  2.3.3 which i believe is installed on mac os by default.